# Plot extremely small values in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to plot some extremely small values with matplotlib in jupiter notebook (on a macbook pro). However, regardless if I set the y-axis limits, all I get is a flat line. What I am after is something like the example (png) below with regard to y-axis notation. Here's my code:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(13,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.hold(True)

ax.plot([0.2, 0.5, 0.8], [4E-300, 5E-300, 4E-300], marker='.')
```

And here's an example of what I am after with regard to y-axis values and notation:

[image]

Even with the following code:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(13,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.hold(True)


xs = np.linspace(0, 1, 101)
ys = 1e-300 * np.exp(-(xs-0.5)**2/0.01)

ax.plot(xs, ys, marker='.')
```

I get the following plot:

[image]

Comment: I agree with both of your observations. I get the plot in the answer by Andrew Walker in version 1.2.0 but I get the plot in the question by spyrostheodoridis using version 1.5.1 of matplotlib

Answer (score -1):

Matplotlib (unlike, say Mathematica) expects you to supply the x- and y- values for all the points of interest in the plot. You could alter you code to evenly evaluate some function (say a gaussian) at even spacing in the unit interval

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(13,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.hold(True)


xs = np.linspace(0, 1, 101)
ys = 1e-300 * np.exp(-(xs-0.5)**2/0.01)
ax.plot(xs, ys, marker='.')
```

Which gives:

[image: plot]