# Plot very small values with matplotlib in jupyter

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

I am trying to plot some extremely small values with matplotlib in jupyter notebook (on a macbook pro). However, regardless if I set the y-axis limits, all I get is a flat line. What I am after is something like the example (png) below with regard to y-axis notation. I also tried the same example outside of jupyter and I still get the same results. Here's the code [suggested by Andrew Walker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40328457/plot-extremely-small-values-in-matplotlib/40328517#40328517) on [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40328457/plot-extremely-small-values-in-matplotlib):

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(13,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.hold(True)


xs = np.linspace(0, 1, 101)
ys = 1e-300 * np.exp(-(xs-0.5)**2/0.01)

ax.plot(xs, ys, marker='.')
```

Here's what I get:

[image]

And here's what I'm after:

[image]

Comment: Having tested it `ax.set_ylim(0, 1e300)` actually sets it to `-0.001` (it returns the limit when setting). The lowest you can go and actually have it work is `ax.set_ylim(0.0,1e-286)`

Comment: `1e-300` is close to the minimum you can represent in a double.  Better to scale your data so you're not in that range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to just plot your values multiplied by 10^300, and then change the y-axis label:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(13,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.hold(True)

xs = np.linspace(0, 1, 101)
ys = np.exp(-(xs-0.5)**2/0.01)

ax.plot(xs, ys, marker='.')

ax.set_ylabel(r'Value [x 10^{-300}]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the set_ylim method on your axes object to do what you need, simply change your code to this and it would do what you need:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(13,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.hold(True)


xs = np.linspace(0, 1, 101)
ys = 1e-300 * np.exp(-(xs-0.5)**2/0.01)

ax.set_ylim([0,10^-299])

ax.plot(xs, ys, marker='.')
```

you may like to check [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777861/setting-y-axis-limit-in-matplotlib) for more info on this subject.

Comment: This doesn't work (try it) — the 1e-299 is too small and matplotlib doesn't accept it as a limit value..